# Text contains search not working next day

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-text

I am executing the following select statement.

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE 0=0 and CONTAINS(address, '%SAMPLE%&%TEXT%')>0;
```

I had created the following indexes on address column.

```
CREATE INDEX MY_TABLE_ADDRESS ON "MY_TABLE" ("ADDRESS");
CREATE INDEX MY_TABLE_ADDRESS_CTX ON "MY_TABLE" ("ADDRESS") INDEXTYPE IS "CTXSYS"."CONTEXT" PARAMETERS ('STOPLIST CTXSYS.EMPTY_STOPLIST');
```

The select statement works one day. But the next day it does not return the result.

I have to drop `MY_TABLE_ADDRESS_CTX` index and run it again to successfully return the result.

I also tried to change the index definition to

```
CREATE INDEX MY_TABLE_ADDRESS_CTX ON "MY_TABLE" ("ADDRESS") INDEXTYPE IS "CTXSYS"."CONTEXT";
```

But this also failed the next day. And I had to re-run the indexing.

Any idea why this is happening? How can I fix the issue so that the search will work always?

Comment: Is something invalidating the index overnight, perhaps? What is the status when the query doesn't find data (according to `all_indexes.status`)?

Comment: @AlexPoole Yeah. we were running a job overnight, that somehow invalidated this index. So had to run sync index to fix the issue. Now the sync index is created as a job which will run after the first job.